# When launching Chrome headless as a command line application process from Java, how do I correctly pass arguments in?

Tags: java, google-chrome, command-line-interface

When I run this from the command line it works fine:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=5000 --dump-dom "https://www.kijiji.ca"
```

(Note: I'm using the 'virtual-time-budget' option to give Chrome extra time to load all dynamic portions of the web page before returning the result.)

When I run this simple 'ls' command from Java, it works fine and I see the output:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] commands = {"ls", "-lah"};
    
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    // Read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

But when I change the `commands` array like to this to run my original command ...

```
    String[] commands = {"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", 
        "--headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=5000 --dump-dom \"https://www.kijiji.ca\""};
```

... it opens a blank Chrome application window.  It doesn't run as a headless command line app, and does not appear to see the command line args.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try all tokens as separate array elements: `String[] cmd = { "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw", "--virtual-time-budget=5000", "--dump-dom", "https://www.kijiji.ca" };`

Comment: @g00se Thanks!  Getting there, it's now running as a cmd line app, but I'm getting this error output: `[0411/091458.736854:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(517)] Failed to serialize document: Uncaught` ... any ideas?

Comment: A Chrome error. That happens without Java too I expect?

Comment: @g00se Yes, it's now happening at the cmd line too, thanks!  Please post your command as an answer and I'll mark it correct!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try all tokens as separate array elements:

```
String[] cmd = { "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw", "--virtual-time-budget=5000", "--dump-dom", "https://www.kijiji.ca" };
```